# Why is the ionization enthalpy of francium greater than that of cesium?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electronic-configuration, atoms, ionization-energy

Why is the ionization enthalpy of francium greater than that of cesium, even though it has a larger size? I found no Google result regarding this.

Comment: [Francium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francium) has a slightly greater ionization enthalpy than Cs. This could due to the [Relativistic Effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_quantum_chemistry)

Comment: Here's [a very similar question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2795/why-does-radium-have-a-higher-first-ionisation-energy-than-barium/). The answer is the same, as barium and radium are also in the s-block, merely one element to the right of your pair.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is the same as in the case of [barium and radium](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2795/why-does-radium-have-a-higher-first-ionisation-energy-than-barium/), a contraction of core electron orbitals with increasing effective nuclear charge. This also changes the shielding (from nuclear charge) of electrons in outer orbitals, and in the end, all $s$ orbitals are contracted and lowered in energy. $s$ orbitals are particularly affected because they have no nodal plane at the nucleus.

This means that the single valence electron in the $7s$ orbital of $\ce{Fr}$ is closer to the nucleus and thus more tightly bound than the $6s$ electron of $\ce{Cs}$. More energy is therefore required to remove the $7s$ electron to form $\ce{Fr+}$ than in the case of $\ce{Cs}$, whose $6s$ electron is more loosely bound.