# Why does Bismuth only create a +3 ion instead of a +5 ion?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

It has 5 valence electrons, but only loses 3 of them to make a +3 ion. Why does this occur?

I believe it may have something to do with how losing 3 electrons leaves you with the p sublevel full, but I do not understand why Bismuth is okay with that.

Comment: *losing 3 electrons leaves you with the p sublevel full* is incorrect.  Removing 3 electrons from Bi results in an electron configuration of [Xe]6s2 4f14 5d10 or an **empty** 6p subshell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isn't it just that +5 is a lot of (positive) charge for a single cation? Which other (transition) metals do form a $\ce{M^{5+}}$ cation? Just out of my mind, I can't think of any.

Typically, these high oxidation states exist in the form of oxo-anions ($\ce{CrO4-}$, $\ce{MnO4-}$, $\ce{VO4^{3-}}$, etc.) and bismuth is no exception here: $\ce{Bi(V)}$ exists as bismutate ($\ce{BiO3-})$.

Comment: I guess you meant $\ce{Bi^{(V)}}$? Also relativistic effects may play an important role lowering the energy of the 6s Orbital.

Comment: @Martin Yes, fixed. And yes, possibly. Apparently, I need more coffee :D

Comment: See also, http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8717/what-is-inert-pair-effect/8774#8774 and http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2795/why-does-radium-have-a-higher-first-ionisation-energy-than-barium for more on the relativist effects.

Comment: I'm not sure why transition metals need to be invoked to answer this question, but a look at the Latimer diagrams of V, Cr, and Mn group transition metals (for example at [webelements](http://www.webelements.com/chromium/compounds.html) we see that there are a number of metals with accessible (V) oxidation states.

Comment: Bismuth can also form oxocations like $\ce{BiO+}$ which is also a +3 ion.