Reaction of radium and water
The reactivity of group 2 metals increases down the group. Radium's location at the bottom of group 2 makes it the most reactive of the group 2 metals. Due to its high reactivity, shouldn't it react explosively with water? However, answers online say the reaction only produces more bubbles. Compare it to the element directly next to it. francium reacts so vigorously with water that a violent explosion is created. So why is the reaction of radium much milder than that of francium, when for both groups the reactivity increases down the group, and they are both located in group 2?

Francium reacts so vigorously with water that a violent explosion is created? How would you get enough of it to make it, if there's about an ounce in whole Earth's crust? And it's in the 1st group. 2nd is much much less reactive.

Why there's so little of it? Because it's very radioactive. A sample large enough to be seen would instantly vaporise from heat of the decay. It you magically got all this ounce in one place, you'd likely get a a violent explosion without water - from the ongoing nuclear reaction.

I wrote similar things, later moving it to the answer.

You don't find chunks of Francium and Radium lying around so you can throw it in the water. They are radioactive so you cannot quantify the reactivity here.

TL;DR: Radium is roughly as reactive as barium and much less reactive than caesium(BrE), rather somewhere between lithium and sodium. But radium alpha decay radiation causes significant ionization that may boost some reactions, creating for radium a reactive environment.

For groups I and II, increasing of electropositivity along the group significantly slows down for heavier group members. It even bends slightly back due Special Relativity effects occurring on $\text{6s}$ and $\text{7s}$ electrons, that move near nuclei at speed comparable to the light speed in vacuum. This effect contracts the respective orbitals, lowers the energy of respective electrons and increases their ionization energy.
Francium is less, not more electropositive than caesium that is the most electropositive element. But the most stable francium isotope has the half time little above 20 minutes. It has never been produced in quantities needed to check its bulk reactivity with water, not even mentioning the extreme security risk if it was done. The claim "Francium reacts so vigorously with water that a violent explosion is created." is made up, as nobody observed it. If we had had a piece of francium for a moment, it would have exploded on its own to francium vapour that would burn in presence of oxygen (due sheer heat generated by its decay).
Between both groups, the respective group II member is much less reactive in contact with water than its group I counterpart in the same period.
If we compare the first ionization energies,
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Element } \ce{(group I)} & \text{IE (eV)} & \text{Element } \ce{(group II)} & \text{IE (eV)} \\
\hline
\ce{Li} & 5.39 & \ce{Be} & 9.32 \\
\ce{Na} & 5.14 & \ce{Mg} & 7.65 \\
\ce{K} & 4.34 & \ce{Ca} & 6.11 \\
\ce{Rb} & 4.18 & \ce{Sr} & 5.69 \\
\ce{Cs} & 3.89 & \ce{Ba} & 5.21 \\
\ce{Fr} & 4.07 & \ce{Ra} & 5.28 \\
\hline
\end{array}
we can get a picture that

Neither francium nor radium are the most electropositive elements of their group.
The baryum and radium electropositivity and assumed reactivity is comparable to lithium and sodium.
Francium is closer to rubidium than to caesium.
Radium is closer to baryum than to strontium.

The quantitative parameter eventually more closely reflecting the reactivity with water is the work function, effectively a ionization energy of a bulk metal surface. Some tabulated data are here. They have roughly the half of the respective IE values, but there are some shifts. Additionally, Wikipedia provides element WF values as well.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Element } \ce{(group I)} & \text{WF (eV)} & \text{Element } \ce{(group II)} & \text{WF (eV)} \\
\hline
\ce{Li} & 2.93 & \ce{Be} & 4.98 \\
\ce{Na} & 2.36 & \ce{Mg} & 3.66 \\
\ce{K} & 2.29 & \ce{Ca} & 2.87 \\
\ce{Rb} & 2.26 & \ce{Sr} & 2.59 \\
\ce{Cs} & 1.95 & \ce{Ba} & 2.52 \\
\ce{Fr} & - & \ce{Ra} & - \\
\hline
\end{array}
In summary, radium is expected to be roughly as reactive as barium and much less reactive than caesium, rather somewhere between lithium and sodium.

Relevant: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2795/why-does-radium-have-a-higher-first-ionisation-energy-than-barium

That is a good reference. Lanthanide contraction plays role as well. (and about  10% of it is reportedly due SR as well).
